# Can`t add cucumberTestResults as a post-build action to my dsl file

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, post-build

I am trying to add the cucumberTestResults as a post-build action to my dsl file. But it is just getting ignored.

```
job('example-atm') {
    scm {
        git {
            branch(branchName)
            remote {
                url(gitUrl)
                credentials(credentialsName)
            }
        }
    }
    triggers {
        scm('H/15 * * * *')
    }
    steps {
        maven('clean test')
    }
    publishers {
        cucumberTestResults {
            jsonReportFiles('./reports/test-report.json')
            ignoreBadSteps()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
publishers {
    cucumber {
        fileIncludePattern('**/*.json')
    }
}
```

It seems that only https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki is the correct wiki. Other pages contained wrong information.